# Getting nosuchmethod exception

Tags: java, reflection, nosuchmethod

Here is my code

```
package first_project;
import java.lang.reflect.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class My_Class {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Getting numbers from user
        System.out.println("Enter First Number:");
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number:");
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        //code for private method
        Class c=addition.class;  
        Method m = addition.class.getDeclaredMethod("add(a,b)");
        m.setAccessible(true);  
        m.invoke(c);
    }
}

package first_project;

//Class for addition
public class addition{
    private void add(int a,int b)
    {
        int ans= a+ b;
        System.out.println("addition:"+ans);
    }
}
```

This is exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: first_project.addition.add(int a,int b)()
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2434)
> at first_project.My_Class.main(My_Class.java:15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line :

```
addition.class.getDeclaredMethod("add(a,b)");
```

to this:

```
Method method = addition.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", int.class, int.class);
```

`getDeclaredMethod` takes method name and its parameters type as argument.

To invoke the method:

```
method.invoke(new addition(), a, b);
```

Comment: Furthermore, when calling `m.invoke` you should pass 3 arguments: the first one is an instance of the class `addition` while the 2nd and 3rd parameters should be your `a` and `b`

Comment: Thanks, missed writing that. Updated the answer.

Comment: The first parameter should be an `instance` of the class, not the class itself. So use `m.invoke(c.newInstance(), a, b);`

Comment: the small "a" in additional got me thinking it was an instance. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: still getting same exception after changing line.Can you please check code in your free time

Comment: did you change this line: `m.invoke(c)` to this: `method.invoke(new addition(), a, b);`

Answer (score 3):

The [`Method.getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) accepts as arguments the method name and the parameter types. You have to change it like this `Method m = addition.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", int.class, int.class);`

The method invocation is also wrong:

```
m.invoke(c);
```

should be:

```
m.invoke(*instance of addition*, *first param*, *second param*);
```

Replace `*instance of addition*` etc. accordingly.

Also, Java uses some [code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) like: the class name must start with a capital letter etc.